# How to store a b-tree into disc?

Tags: java, b-tree

I created a b-tree using Java in memory, which has get(K key), put(K key,V value) method, just like HashMap. I had to store the b-tree into disc because the size becomes huge, Then I stored each node of tree as an file into disc, use file name to keep the pointer. When doing search, only few files needed will be load into memory. even though, I was not happy that a lot of files was created. any brilliant idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON: it is a very convenient way for serializing / deserializing data.

Using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/):

```
public static void writeToDisc(MyBTree myBTree, File file) throws IOException {
    new ObjectMapper().writeValue(file, myBTree);
}

public static MyBTree readFromDisc(File file) throws IOException {
    return new ObjectMapper().readValue(file, MyBTree.class);
}
```

Comment: yes, but I cant to load the whole b-tree because it's size is too huge to load into memory. that is why I save the node(object) as single file. the question may be how to write many nodes to one file, and then load the specific node when need,not all.

Comment: Why not write to different files? One per node using the same technique?